# Is there a tool to help find bugs or perform static analysis in Python?

Tags: python, debugging, static-analysis

Is there any tool to help to find bugs or perform static analysis in Python?

I search this question in Google i found answer - **Pychecker** 
But i try to use pychecker its not work for **import modules**.
Is it possible to debug the program along with checking the package is present or not.

Comment: "But i try to use pychecker its not work for import modules" This sentence does *not* have any meaning. Please show what happens when you launch pychecker, and what you think should be the expected output. Also consider using `pylint` which includes some functionality of `pychecker` plus coding-style checks.

Answer (score 3):

Go with **pylint**. It will detect imported modules are present or not.

Check out the more details on ***http://www.pylint.org***

Also check simple program where I have imported test module which is not present.

when I run pylint on this I am able to detect following:

```
root@mahesh-pike:/tmp# pylint prog.py

No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module prog F:  5, 0: Unable to import 'test' (EOL while scanning string literal (<string>, line 1)) (import-error)
```

Go with pylint, it will help you lot.